# How to prove $v_{p}(x!-y!)=v_{p}(y!)$ for $p|x$, $p|y$ and $x > y$

Tags: number-theory

Let $x,y$ be postive integers and $p$ be a prime number such that $x>y$ and $p|x$,$p|y$. Prove or disprove that 
$$v_{p}(x!-y!)=v_{p}(y!),$$
where $v_{p}$ denotes the largest power of $p$ that divides $n$.

Since $x>y$, $y!|x!$ and
$$x!-y!=y![x(x-1)\cdots (y+1)-1].$$

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: You mean $v_p(n)$ is the largest power of p that divides n.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is clear that since $x>y$ then $p^{v_p(y!)}\mid x!-y!$ for any common prime factor $p$ of $x$ and $y$ and so it remains to show that $v_p(y!)$ is in fact the largest integer $t$ for which $p^t\mid x!-y!.$ Suppose not. Then $p^{v_p(y!)+1}\mid x!-y!.$ It follows from the identity you derived that $p\mid x(x-1)\cdots(y+1)-1,$ which is a contradiction since $p\mid x.$ Therefore $p^{v_p(y!)+1}\nmid x!-y!$ and hence $v_p(x!-y!)=v_p(y!).$

Comment: sorry, $x$ also such $p|x$.

Comment: @Thailandasw I have edited my answer.